# flutter_native_splash package: image does not scale down on Android

Tags: android, flutter, native, splash-screen, pubspec

I got an issue with the flutter_native_splash library. The image does not scale down and it simply looks ugly. For iOS, it's now problem and looks very nice. But on Android it seems to be a problem. Here is the code of my pubspec.yaml:

```
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#FFFFFF"
  image: assets/images/ci/21vision_logo.png
  image_dark: assets/images/ci/21vision_logo_inverted.png
  color_dark: "#202124"
  web: false

  android_12:
    branding: assets/images/ci/21vision_logo.png
    icon_background_color: "#ffffff"
    image_dark: assets/images/ci/21vision_logo_inverted.png
    icon_background_color_dark: "#121212"
```

[image: Splash screen for Android - image does not scale down]

Answer (score 0):

What does your asset directory look like? Are you providing that image for the different screen densities?

ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi

Comment: No I did not. But the documentation of the flutter_native_splash package does only required the actual png file and resized it itself or did I get that wrong?